# Symfony2 - get value displayed to user for choice field in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to display the "label" (ie, value displayed to user) of a choice field in my twig template. I'm using Symfony 2.3. I just need the label associated with the actual current value of the field.

I finally figured out a way to do it that requires looping through every choice option, but am now wondering if there is a more efficient way? Here is my working code:

```
{% for choice in form.myfield.vars.choices %}
  {% if choice.value == form.myfield.vars.value %}
    {{ choice.label }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm looking for something like this (non-working code):

```
{{ form.myfield.vars.choices[form.myfield.vars.value].label }}
```

Is there a more efficient way, or is my solution the best possible?

Comment: if you need to customize form rendering you should just create a form_theme  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming